# Warning: Stateless function components cannot be given refs in NavLink, styled-components

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I am getting the following error in `React 16.8`:

Warning: Stateless function components cannot be given refs. Attempts to access this ref will fail.

```
Check the render method of `Button`.
    in NavLink (created by Button)
    in Button
    in Unknown (created by StyledComponents__ButtonLink)
    in StyledComponents__ButtonLink (created by PageHeaderLayout)
    in div (created by PageHeaderLayout)
    in b (created by PageHeaderLayout)
    in div (created by GridColumn)
    in GridColumn (created by PageHeaderLayout)
    in div (created by GridRow)
    in GridRow (created by PageHeader__PageHeaderRow)
    in PageHeader__PageHeaderRow (created by PageHeaderLayout)
    in PageHeaderLayout (created by PageHeader)
    in PageHeader (created by Connect(PageHeader))
    in Connect(PageHeader) (created by Route)
    in Route
    in Switch
    in Unknown (created by BaseLayout)
    in div (created by Grid)
    in Grid (created by BaseLayout__ContentGrid)
    in BaseLayout__ContentGrid (created by BaseLayout)
    in div (created by BaseLayout__LayoutContainer)
    in BaseLayout__LayoutContainer (created by BaseLayout)
    in BaseLayout
    in Router (created by BrowserRouter)
    in BrowserRouter
    in AppContainer
    in Provider
```

It happens in the following code:

```
      <b><br />
        {entityLinks.map(({ popup, ...linkProps }) =>
          <div key={linkProps.content}>
            <ButtonLink as={NavLink} {...linkProps} />
            {popup && <Popup content={popup} trigger={<Icon name="help circle outline" color="grey" />} />}
          </div>,
        )}  
      </b>
```

Where `ButtonLink` is:

```
import React from 'react'
import styled from 'styled-components'
import { Button } from 'semantic-ui-react'

export const ButtonLink = styled(({ color, padding, ...props }) => <Button {...props} />).attrs({ basic: true })` 
  &.ui.button.basic {
    white-space: nowrap;
    ...
    ...
```

The `entityLinks` that are passed to the `ButtonLink` is just an array of such a structure:

```
const entityLinks = [{
  to: `/variant_search/${searchType}/${searchId}`,
  content: `${snakecaseToTitlecase(searchType)} Variant Search`,
  disabled,
  popup: disabled ? 'Search is disabled until data is loaded' : null,
}]
```

How could I fix that? I went over multiple similar threads but still can't fix it in this particular case. Here is also how the expanded `React` code in `Chrome` looks:

[image]

Comment: Maybe you cannot pass ref to `Button`. Maybe it comes from styled-components

Comment: `styled({ color, padding, ...props })` gets the very same `entityLinks` - object, just without the `popup`. I checked it and what is passed is just a bunch of strings (`to`, `content`) and one boolean - `disabled`. Or you mean its something very peculiar to the `styled-components` itself? Then maybe I should post an issue on their `github`...

Comment: I know that styled-components forwards ref. maybe share some codesandbox example so we could debug

Comment: Thats hard for me, but I will try...